# DB Connection Leak in Item Reader when using AsyncTaskExecutor

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-batch

In the spring batch job that we have developed we are using the AsyncTaskExecutor, to allow for parallel processing at a step level. We have the concurrency limit set as 5. We use  the JDBCCursorItemReader to pick-up the input records that we need to process. The JDBCCursorItemReader is configured to pick up connections for a connection pool.  On job execution we have noticed that the job aborts due to the exhaustion of connections in the pool, leading us to believe that the JDBCCursorItemReader is not releasing the connections back to the connection pool. Any suggestion?

Below is my batch xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <beans:import resource="../launch-context.xml" />

    <beans:bean id="wsStudentItemReader"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcCursorItemReader"    
        scope="step">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="rptDS" />
        <beans:property name="sql"
            value="SELECT * FROM STUDENTS WHERE BATCH_ID=?" />
        <beans:property name="preparedStatementSetter">
            <beans:bean class="com.test.BatchDtSetter"
                autowire="byName">
                <beans:property name="batchId" value="#{jobParameters[batchId]}" /> 
            </beans:bean>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="rowMapper" ref="wsRowMapper" />
    </beans:bean>


 <beans:bean id="outputWriter"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.support.ClassifierCompositeItemWriter">
        <beans:property name="classifier" ref="writerClassifier" >      
        </beans:property>       
 </beans:bean>  

<beans:bean id="writerClassifier"
    class="com.test.WriterClassifier">
    <beans:property name="codeFailWriter" ref="failJdbcBatchItemWriter" />
    <beans:property name="codePassWriter" ref="passJdbcBatchItemWriter"></beans:property>
</beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="failJdbcBatchItemWriter"
        class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="rptDS" />
        <beans:property name="sql"
            value="DELETE FROM STUDENTS WHERE BATCH_ID=?" />
        <beans:property name="itemPreparedStatementSetter" ref="FailStatusSetter" />
    </beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="FailStatusSetter" class="com.test.FailStatusSetter" />

    <beans:bean id="passJdbcBatchItemWriter"
        class="com.test.PassBatchItemWriter">
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="WSListnr"
        class="com.test.WSBatchListnr">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="rptDS" />
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="wsRowMapper" class="com.test.WSReqMapper" />
    <beans:bean id="wsReqPrcsr" 
         class="com.test.WSReqProc">
         <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="rptDS" />
    </beans:bean>
    <beans:bean id="wsReqPrepStmtSetter" class="com.test.wsStudentSetter" />

    <step id="initiateStep">
        <tasklet ref="initiateStepTask" />
    </step>
    <step id="wsStudentGenStep">
        <tasklet task-executor="taskExecutor">
            <chunk reader="wsStudentItemReader" processor="wsReqPrcsr"
                writer="outputWriter" commit-interval="4" skip-limit="20">
                <skippable-exception-classes>
                    <include class="java.lang.Exception" />
                </skippable-exception-classes>
            </chunk>
            <listeners> 
                <listener ref="WSListnr" />
            </listeners>            
        </tasklet>
    </step>
    <job id="wsStudent">
        <step id="wsStudentFileGenIntialStep" parent="initiateStep"
            next="wsStudentFileGenStep" />
        <step id="wsStudentFileGenStep" parent="wsStudentGenStep" />
    </job>


    <beans:bean id="initiateStepTask" class="com.test.Initializer"
        scope="step">
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="taskExecutor"
       class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor">
       <beans:property name="concurrencyLimit" value="2"/>
   </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

Config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.test" />
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:batch.properties" />

        <beans:bean id="websiteDS"
    class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="jndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/WebSiteDS" />
    <beans:property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false" />
    <beans:property name="cache" value="true" /> 
    <beans:property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource" />
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="rptDS"
    class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="jndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/ReportingDS" />
    <beans:property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false" />
    <beans:property name="cache" value="true" />
    <beans:property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource" />
</beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager"
        lazy-init="true">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="rptDS" />
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="jobRepository"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean"
        p:databaseType="db2" p:transactionManager-ref="transactionManager"
        p:dataSource-ref="batchDS" p:isolation-level-for-create="ISOLATION_REPEATABLE_READ" />


    <beans:bean id="jobLauncher" 
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher">
        <beans:property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" /> 
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="jobOperator"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobOperator"
        p:jobLauncher-ref="jobLauncher" p:jobExplorer-ref="jobExplorer"
        p:jobRepository-ref="jobRepository" p:jobRegistry-ref="jobRegistry" />

    <beans:bean id="jobExplorer"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.JobExplorerFactoryBean"
        p:dataSource-ref="batchDS" />

    <beans:bean id="jobRegistry"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.MapJobRegistry" />
    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.support.JobRegistryBeanPostProcessor">
        <beans:property name="jobRegistry" ref="jobRegistry" />
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="completionPolicy" class="org.springframework.batch.repeat.policy.DefaultResultCompletionPolicy"/> 


</beans:beans>
```

Also refer, [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor trying to read record after completion of processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15587166/simpleasynctaskexecutor-trying-to-read-record-after-completion-of-processing), as both the issues might be related

Comment: "Any suggestion?" - Check if the JDBCCursorItemReader is releasing the connections?? Can you give us some code?

Comment: post your config file please.

Comment: @Cygnusx1: added configs

Comment: please show the config for the rptds datasource also, is it a com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2ConnectionPoolDataSource?

Comment: @MichaelPralow: corrected ds name. Used similar config for all ds. Also refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15587166/simpleasynctaskexecutor-trying-to-read-record-after-completion-of-processing, as both the issues might be related

Comment: how do you know, that you are using a datasource pool? DB2SimpleDataSource is not providing a pool (see IBM doc)

Comment: @MichaelPralow: corrected, but this data source is not the problem as I have tested with all other jobs and it is using connection from the pool. Issue is specifically noticed when using SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor

Comment: by reading the javadoc from the jdbcreader i saw: "By default the cursor will be opened using a separate connection", can you try it with the JdbcPagingItemReader? multi-threading is directly mentioned there

Comment: @MichaelPralow: thanks for the suggestion. Using JdbcPagingItemReader I could resolve my issue. Please add this as answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved by using JdbcPagingItemReader.

Also refer:
[SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor trying to read record after completion of processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15587166/simpleasynctaskexecutor-trying-to-read-record-after-completion-of-processing/16523977#16523977)

Thanks @MichaelPralow